# Resource Linking Failed/Android Studio College Project

Tags: android, error-handling

I have been trying to build the project but I keep on facing problems while building it, can anyone please help me out.

The Code Is Below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 26+ -->
        <item name="colorError">?android:attr/colorError</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 26+ -->
        <item name="colorError">?android:attr/colorError</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:touchscreenBlocksFocus">true</item>
        <item name="android:keyboardNavigationCluster">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" parent="Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"/>
</resources>
```

The colors.xml File is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

And The Error I am Getting Is Below

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/arsalan/Downloads/Development/Pixlr/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeEditerDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/Users/arsalan/Downloads/Development/Pixlr/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeEditerDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/Users/arsalan/Downloads/Development/Pixlr/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeEditerDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Can someone please help me out, I have to submit this project to my college. Also the system configuration is below -

Computer Model - Macbook Air 2018 (256GB)
Software Model - Android Studio 3.3 (Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772)
JRE            - 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM            - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
OS Version     - macOS 10.14.2

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. The same also applies to the macos tag. Please read the tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use at least api level 26 in you build.gradle
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Comment: This is my gradle file 

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    flavorDimensions "default"
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
        multiDexEnabled true